# Show JFrame in a specific screen in dual monitor configuration

Tags: java, swing, jframe, multiple-monitors

I have a dual monitor config and I want to run my GUI in a specific monitor if it is found.  I tried to create my `JFrame` window passing a `GraphicConfiguration` object of my screen device, but it doesn't work, frame still display on the main screen.

How can I set the screen where my frame must be displayed?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
public static void showOnScreen( int screen, JFrame frame )
{
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment
        .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice[] gs = ge.getScreenDevices();
    if( screen > -1 && screen < gs.length )
    {
        gs[screen].setFullScreenWindow( frame );
    }
    else if( gs.length > 0 )
    {
        gs[0].setFullScreenWindow( frame );
    }
    else
    {
        throw new RuntimeException( "No Screens Found" );
    }
}
```

Comment: But why this relates with "full screen"? What if I need not use full screen mode?

Comment: @Dims, I gave a new answer that doesn't force full-screen.

Comment: This didn't work for me on a vertical dual monitor setup. Although both are detected in GraphicsDevices, the frame is always shown on the main monitor.

Answer (score 41):

I have modified @Joseph-gordon's answer to allow for a way to achieve this without forcing full-screen:

```
public static void showOnScreen( int screen, JFrame frame ) {
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice[] gd = ge.getScreenDevices();
    if( screen > -1 && screen < gd.length ) {
        frame.setLocation(gd[screen].getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds().x, frame.getY());
    } else if( gd.length > 0 ) {
        frame.setLocation(gd[0].getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds().x, frame.getY());
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException( "No Screens Found" );
    }
}
```

In this code I am assuming `getDefaultConfiguration()` will never return null. If that is not the case then someone please correct me. But, this code works to move your `JFrame` to the desired screen.

Comment: This solution only works, if the devices are not aligned vertically. Replace `frame.getY()` with `gd[0].getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds().y + frame.getY()` to fix this issue.

Comment: This solution (also with @Ercksen 's comment) works fine but the window is slightly off-centered. To fix that call `frame.setExtendedState(frame.getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);` at the end or after the `showOnScreen(SCREEN_ID, frame)` call

Comment: what is that int screen for? is that index of 0 and 1 code as if the 1st monitor & 2nd monitor ?

Answer (score 6):

I have modified @Joseph-gordon and @ryvantage answer to allow for a way to achieve this without forcing full-screen, fixed screen configuration position and center it on select screen:

```
public void showOnScreen(int screen, JFrame frame ) {
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice[] gd = ge.getScreenDevices();
    int width = 0, height = 0;
    if( screen > -1 && screen < gd.length ) {
        width = gd[screen].getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds().width;
        height = gd[screen].getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds().height;
        frame.setLocation(
            ((width / 2) - (frame.getSize().width / 2)) + gd[screen].getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds().x, 
            ((height / 2) - (frame.getSize().height / 2)) + gd[screen].getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds().y
        );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException( "No Screens Found" );
    }
}
```

Comment: The reference to 'display' on line 5 is undefined. What does this refer to?

Comment: This works perfectly for me in a vertical setup.

Answer (score 4):

A much cleaner solution after reading the docs for JFrame.setLocationRelativeTo
Display on screen 2

```
public void moveToScreen() {
    setVisible(false);
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice[] screens = ge.getScreenDevices();
    int n = screens.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (screens[i].getIDstring().contentEquals(settings.getScreen())) {
            JFrame dummy = new JFrame(screens[i].getDefaultConfiguration());
            setLocationRelativeTo(dummy);
            dummy.dispose();
        }
    }
    setVisible(true);
}
```

This function can be used to switch application window between screens

Comment: What exactly is settings?

Comment: It's probably the output of some settings parser which has a field of String called screen.

Comment: interface with a frame to be positionned?

Answer (score 2):

Please Refer to [GraphicsDevice](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html) API, you have a good example there.

Comment: ? seems to create some frame on each screen

Answer (score 2):

With everyone chipping in with their **own flavors**, based on other flavors, **I add mine** because the others locked you in with regards to positioning of the window on the selected screen.

**It is simply the best.** It allows you to set the location on the other screen as well.

```
public void setLocation( int screen, double x, double y ) {
        GraphicsEnvironment g = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice[]    d = g.getScreenDevices();

        if ( screen >= d.length ) {
                screen = d.length - 1;
        }

        Rectangle bounds = d[screen].getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();
        
        // Is double?
        if ( x == Math.floor(x) && !Double.isInfinite(x) ) {
                x *= bounds.x;  // Decimal -> percentage
        }
        if ( y == Math.floor(y) && !Double.isInfinite(y) ) {
                y *= bounds.y;  // Decimal -> percentage
        }

        x = bounds.x      + x;
        y = jframe.getY() + y;

        if ( x > bounds.x) x = bounds.x;
        if ( y > bounds.y) y = bounds.y;

        // If double we do want to floor the value either way 
        jframe.setLocation((int)x, (int)y);
}
```

**Example:**

```
setLocation(2, 200, 200);
```

Even allows you to pass in a percentage for the screen position!

```
setLocation(2, 0.5, 0);     // Place on right edge from the top down if combined with setSize(50%, 100%);
```

screen must be larger than 0, which I am sure is a tough requirement!

To place on last, simply call with **Integer.MAX_VALUE.**

Answer (score 1):

My experience is with extending desktops across multiple monitors, versus configuring the monitors as separate (X11) displays. If that's not what you want to do, this won't apply.

And my solution was a bit of a hack: I called `Toolkit.getScreenSize()`, determined if I was in a multi-monitor situation (by comparing the height to the width and assuming that width > twice height indicated multi-monitor), then setting the initial X and Y position of the frame.

Comment: Thank you for adivice. I solved using    jframe.setBounds(graphicConfiguration.getBounds())

Answer (score 1):

based on @ryvantage answer, I improved it so it is displayed in the center of the screen:

```
private static void showOnScreen( int screen, Window frame ) {
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice[] gd = ge.getScreenDevices();
    GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice;
    if( screen > -1 && screen < gd.length ) {
        graphicsDevice = gd[screen];
    } else if( gd.length > 0 ) {
        graphicsDevice = gd[0];
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException( "No Screens Found" );
    }
    Rectangle bounds = graphicsDevice.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();
    int screenWidth = graphicsDevice.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
    int screenHeight = graphicsDevice.getDisplayMode().getHeight();
    frame.setLocation(bounds.x + (screenWidth - frame.getPreferredSize().width) / 2,
            bounds.y + (screenHeight - frame.getPreferredSize().height) / 2);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me worked well also (supposing left monitor has size 1920x1200):

A) set on left monitor on some exact position:

`newFrame.setBounds(200,100,400,200)`

B) set on right monitor on some exact position:

`newFrame.setBounds(2000,100,200,100)`

C) set on left monitor maximized:

`newFrame.setBounds(200,100,400,200)`
`newFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH)`

D) set on right monitor maximized

`newFrame.setBounds(2000,100,200,100)`
`newFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH)`

Answer (score 0):

Many of the solutions here works for extended displays. If you are using separate displays just pass the graphics configuration object of the desired graphics device to the constructor of jframe or jdialog.

Answer (score 0):

Vickys answer contains the right pointer. It is new JFrame(GraphicsConfiguration gc) that does it.

You can do it like that:

```
GraphicsDevice otherScreen = getOtherScreen(this);
JFrame frameOnOtherScreen = new JFrame(otherScreen.getDefaultConfiguration());

private GraphicsDevice getOtherScreen(Component component) {
    GraphicsEnvironment graphicsEnvironment = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    if (graphicsEnvironment.getScreenDevices().length == 1) {
        // if there is only one screen, return that one
        return graphicsEnvironment.getScreenDevices()[0];
    }

    GraphicsDevice theWrongOne = component.getGraphicsConfiguration().getDevice();
    for (GraphicsDevice dev : graphicsEnvironment.getScreenDevices()) {
        if (dev != theWrongOne) {
            return dev;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If u want to set it to center of left screen:

```
int halfScreen = (int)(screenSize.width/2);
                frame.setLocation((halfScreen - frame.getSize().width)/2, (screenSize.height - frame.getSize().height)/2);
```

If u want to set it to center of right screen:

```
int halfScreen = (int)(screenSize.width/2);
                frame.setLocation((halfScreen - frame.getSize().width)/2 + halfScreen, (screenSize.height - frame.getSize().height)/2);
```