# Output jFrame to second monitor if possible

Tags: java, swing, jframe, multiple-monitors

i have a jFrame on Swing in Java, and i want it to output to second monitor, if this monitor exists.

I tried this (by [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html) page) to get resolutions of displays

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice[] gs = ge.getScreenDevices();
for (int j = 0; j < gs.length; j++)
{
    GraphicsConfiguration[] gc =  gs[j].getConfigurations();
    for (int i = 0; i < gc.length; i++)
    {
        Rectangle gcBounds = gc[i].getBounds();
        int xoffs = gcBounds.x;
        int yoffs = gcBounds.y;
    }
}
```

But then i watch in debugger to xoffs and yoffs for 
my first monitor (1360*768) xoffs = 1360  and yoffs = 0
second monitor (1280*1024) xoffs = 0 and yoffs = 0

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627553/java-show-jframe-in-a-specific-screen-in-dual-monitor-configuration

Comment: In that question they use method setFullScreenWindow( frame ) to set jFrame full size, but i don't want to make it full size frame. But now i want to get dimensions on first monitor, and shift by this numbers to display form on second monitor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
   java.awt.GraphicsDevice[] devices = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices();

   for ( int i = 0; i < devices.length; i++ )
   {
      System.out.println( "Device " + i + " width: " + devices[ i ].getDisplayMode().getWidth() );
      System.out.println( "Device " + i + " height: " + devices[ i ].getDisplayMode().getHeight() );
   }
}
```

Comment: disagreed if is there more than one GPU, btw +1

Comment: Thanks, it's work, it's output correct resolutions. And i havn't PC's with several GPU's, so it's work fine for me