# How do I get my application to appear on the center of my second monitor, not my main?

Tags: java, jframe

I am trying to get my application to appear on the center of the second monitor as my main monitor has the code on. I am using `window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);`, but do not know what I would use to place it on the other monitor. How can I get my application to appear on the second monitor?

Comment: It is a question, I've noticed SO is full of irritants like you who nit-pick all the time. Rather than nit-pick petty, little things, how about you actually try and help me?

Comment: I don't know the answer, I'm trying to help you get more help out of the nitpicky people who _do_ know how to help you.

Comment: But your edit was `nit-picky`, it was unnecessary. If someone were to help me, then I'm sure that removing a line regarding a thought would not make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `GraphicsEnvironment` and `GraphicsDevice` class's seems to be the way to go for this.  By obtaining the environment you can check for `GraphicsDevices` such as screens and then place your frame on the relevant device if found.  If you look at this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627553/java-show-jframe-in-a-specific-screen-in-dual-monitor-configuration) there are several answers which should be able to provide you with what you want.

Good Luck!