# Center JFrame on Second Screen or Monitor - Java

Tags: java, jframe

I am trying to open a JFrame on the second screen and to center it. I can open JFrame on the second screen but how to center it. Here is a sample code I made:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Question {

public Question() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    f.getContentPane().add(panel);
    f.pack();
    f.setTitle("Hello");
    f.setSize(200,200);
    showOnScreen(1,f);
    f.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new Question();
        }
    };
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
}
public static void showOnScreen( int screen, JFrame frame ) {
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice[] gd = ge.getScreenDevices();
    if( screen > -1 && screen < gd.length ) {
         frame.setLocation(gd[screen].getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds().x, frame.getY());
    } else if( gd.length > 0 ) {
        frame.setLocation(gd[0].getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds().x, frame.getY());
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException( "No Screens Found" );
    }
}

}
```

I tried something like this to center it in second screen:

```
frame.setLocation((gd[screen].getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds().x*3/2)-200, ((gd[screen].getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds().height)/2)-200);
```

It works but i don't want to hard code because later in the actual program, the frame size change.

Also i tried this:

```
frame.setLocation((gd[screen].getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds().width)/2-frame.getSize().width/2, (gd[screen].getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds().height)/2-frame.getSize().height/2);
```

But then it opens it on the first screen. Makes sense.

Please someone can help to apply the right fix. Appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: put `f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);` before or after `f.setVisible()`

Comment: It then opens the frame on first screen instead. I wan't it to open it and center it in second screen.

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627553/java-show-jframe-in-a-specific-screen-in-dual-monitor-configuration)

Comment: Thanks Madhan. That was the page which i referred too earlier. I got a solution. Check it below. Let me know if you see any issues.

Comment: As long as it solves your problem then it's ok

Answer (score 2):

This is how i solved. My application can have max two screens.

```
  public void showOnScreen( int screen, JFrame frame ) {
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice[] gd = ge.getScreenDevices();
    if( screen > 0 && screen < 2 ) {
        int x = frame.getWidth()/2;
        int y = frame.getHeight()/2;
        frame.setLocation((gd[screen].getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds().width * 3/2) - x,   (gd[screen].getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds().height *1/2) - y);
    } else if( gd.length > 0 ) {
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException( "No Screens Found" );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To show centered on a secondary screen (last, in this example) I did this:

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice[] gd = ge.getScreenDevices();
GraphicsConfiguration gc = gd[gd.length - 1].getDefaultConfiguration();
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(new JFrame(gd));
```

as per `setLocationRelativeTo(Component c)` documentation:

> If the component is not null, but it is not currently showing, the
>   window is placed in the center of the target screen defined by the
>   GraphicsConfiguration associated with this component.