# Launching a JDialog at the center of screen in a multi screen environment in an intellij plugin

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

I am writing a plugin for intellij. I am launching a JDialog when a menu item is clicked. The problem is that the JDialog opens at the top left corner of screen. I tried using setLocationRelativeTo(null) but it placed the dialog at the center of the first screen while the intellij IDE was open on some other screen.

An answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627553/java-show-jframe-in-a-specific-screen-in-dual-monitor-configuration) says how to use GraphicsEnvironment api to position a Window in a particular screen, but then how do I specify which screen the intellij IDE is launched in.

Comment: Do you have reference of the parent `Window/JFrame` in your plugin development environment?

Comment: Yes, parent window was required and I found suggestParentWindow function in the WindowManager.java which returns a parent window. I just searched for this randomly and I am not sure if there exists any other way to get the root Window in intellij idea that I can use as a parent window. This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you somehow can get the parent `Window/Frame` reference you can find out in which `GraphicDevice` the Intellij is being rendered:

```
JWindow parentWindow = ... // reference to your plugin parent window
GraphicsConfiguration cfg = myWindow.getGraphicsConfiguration();
GraphicsDevice intellijScr = cfg .getDevice();
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice[] allDevices = ge.getScreenDevices();
int intellijScrIndex = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < allDevices.length; i++) 
{
    if (allDevices[i].equals(intellijScr))
    {
        myScreenIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

From now on, I think you are good to go with the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627553/java-show-jframe-in-a-specific-screen-in-dual-monitor-configuration) you've found before.

Good Luck.