# Java game won't render on second monitor

Tags: java, awt, game-engine, graphics2d

I'm creating a game in java using Graphics2D and the Canvas class.

When I run the program a JFrame appears on my first monitor and there are no problems. However, when I drag the JFrame onto my second monitor it turns gray and will stop rendering anything, then when I drag it back onto my first monitor the program continues rendering..

My game loop calls a `draw()` method in my `Screen` class that extends `Canvas`, This is the draw method.

```
public void draw(){
    BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null){
        createBufferStrategy(2);
        bs = getBufferStrategy();
        g = (Graphics2D) bs.getDrawGraphics();
    }

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.drawString("Hello, this works", 300, 300);

    g.drawImage(ImageLoader.test[0][0], 100, 100, null);

    bs.show();
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627553/show-jframe-in-a-specific-screen-in-dual-monitor-configuration , hope this helps :)

Comment: Nope that doesn't help. The code in that puts the JFrame onto my other screen but if I drag it across screens it breaks again. I want to be able to drag my Jframe between monitors without it breaking.

Comment: if you put sort-of this type of script in a loop or event I believe it would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not keep a reference to a Graphics (or Graphics2D) object beyond the scope of your method.

Move `g = (Graphics2D) bs.getDrawGraphics();` outside of your if-block.  You need to obtain a new Graphics each time you draw.

You also need to [dispose](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#dispose--) of the Graphics as soon as you're done drawing on it.

Using a BufferStrategy is a little complicated.  I recommend you look at the example code in the [BufferStrategy documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html).  In particular, you need to surround your rendering with loops that check the values returned by the BufferStrategy's `contentsRestored()` and `contentsLost()` methods.

Comment: Thank you, this has also fixed another problem I have where the game seems to break everytime it's resized.